# 3.3v pin on a 5v Pro Micro?

Tags: power, arduino-pro-micro, voltage

I have a arduino pro micro that runs on 5v. 
I also have a Max4466 that needs 3.3v, however the pro micro doesn't seem to have a 3.3v VCC. 
Is there any way to attach the max4466 to the Board?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an external 3.3V voltage regulator. You can get these quite cheap on eBay (etc) as a module - some even come in a breadboard friendly format.

Power it from the 5V from the Arduino, then power your MAX4466.

However, the MAX4466 can run at up to 5.5V, so I fail to see why you think you need 3.3V.

Comment: Thanks for giving a solution, so upvoted. The solution is missing from the link of my deleted answer. For completeness, I repeat your mentioned link here: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/why-you-cant-use-resistors-voltage-regulator